# How to capture time portion from date_time in pyspark pr sparksql?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have field visit_start_time_gmt in bigint format, I was able to convert it to date_time, but now I need to remove the time portion of the timestamp in another column, see data sample below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **truncate time** then use [**`date_trunc()`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/sql/#date_trunc) function.

- If you want to convert to date then use **`to_date`()** function.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+--------------------+
#|visit_start_time_gmt|
#+--------------------+
#|          1522555602|
#|          1522622390|
#+--------------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("date_hour",date_trunc("HOUR",to_timestamp(col("visit_start_time_gmt")))).\
withColumn("date",to_date(to_timestamp(col("visit_start_time_gmt")))).\
show()
+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
|visit_start_time_gmt|          date_hour|      date|
+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
|          1522555602|2018-04-01 04:00:00|2018-04-01|
|          1522622390|2018-04-01 22:00:00|2018-04-01|
+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
```